# Run a loop over several different file paths

Tags: python, loops, file, path

I have a list of file paths in one text document called list_paths that looks something like this (there are no blank lines in the document btw):

```
/users/myname/Documents/test1.txt 
/users/myname/Documents/test2.txt 
/users/myname/Documents/test3.txt 
/users/myname/Documents/test4.txt
```

I have a working code that takes a text file but I want it to go to this file (listpaths) and loop through each specific path to get information such that I don't have to enter them individually.

Something along the lines of:

```
with open(list_paths, "r") as file:
for line in file:
    line.strip("\n")
    fp = line      

with open(fp, "r") as file:
[The rest of my code]
```

So that way my code can run on each specific file without me having to manually put in each file path.

Comment: what is your question? you have an almost working code, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply read your file's path using [`readlines`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm) function,
and then just open each of them

```
with open(file_list_path, "r") as flp:
    files_list = flp.readlines()
    for file in files_list:
        with open(file, "r") as f:
        # your stuff here for each file(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

The strip of the `\n` character is not done in place!

```
with open(list_paths, "r") as file1:
    for line in file1:
        fp = line.strip("\n")
        with open(fp, "r") as file2:
            [The rest of my code]
```

Comment: I'm getting the error following error, any idea how to fix it?: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/karel/Documents/test1.txt'

Comment: @helpmeplease That really depends on the rest of your code, how can I know what you are doing? :)